# CSS and JS files can't be found in a github project page

Tags: angular, github, github-pages

I have an Angular2 app that runs well locally. I built the app using Angular CLI and uploaded it to a [gh-pages branch of a repo](https://github.com/phuwin/yugioh-thecardgame/tree/gh-pages), but for some reasons [the project page](https://phuwin.github.io/yugioh-thecardgame/) doesn't work properly. Only the `index.htm`l file is loaded, the rest aren't pointed to the correct directory:

[image]

I inspected a working project page [Angular datatable](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome) and here is what it's shown in the dev tool:
[image]
[Link](https://github.com/phuwin/yugioh-thecardgame/tree/gh-pages) to the gh-pages branch of the repo.
[Link](https://phuwin.github.io/yugioh-thecardgame/) to the project page.
Is this a fault from github server side or did I do something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Your index.html page has `<base href="/">`, although the base href should in fact be `/yugioh-thecardgame/`. See the --base-href option in https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Comment: I fix this with using `ng build --base-href ./`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea. If you're on /yugioh-thecardgame/foo/bar and refresh the page, it will look for assets in /yugioh-thecardgame/foo/bar

Comment: @JBNizet I tried `ng build --base-href /yugioh-thecardgame/`, the base ref returned is "C:\Program Files\yugioh-thecardgame\" Do you have any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: No, sorry. I've never used that option.